# How do I decrease the governance cost of the following code

Tags: javascript, netsuite

It netsuite there is a limit on how frequently you can use certain APIs (as well as certain scripts).  For what I am doing I believe the following is the applicable cost:
nlapiLoadSearch: 5
nlobjSearchResultSet.getSearch(): 10 
It takes about an hour, but every time my script(which follows) errors out, probably due to this.  How do I change it to make it have less governance cost?

```
function walkCat2(catId, pad){
var loadCategory = nlapiLoadRecord("sitecategory", "14958149");   
var dupRecords = nlapiLoadSearch('Item', '1951');   //load saved search
var resultSet = dupRecords.runSearch();   //run saved search
resultSet.forEachResult(function(searchResult)
    {
    var InterID=(searchResult.getValue('InternalID'));   // process- search 
var LINEINX=loadCategory.getLineItemCount('presentationitem'); 
loadCategory.insertLineItem("presentationitem",LINEINX); 
loadCategory.setLineItemValue("presentationitem", "presentationitem", LINEINX, InterID+'INVTITEM');  //--- Sets the line value.-jf
nlapiSubmitRecord(loadCategory , true);
    return true;                // return true to keep iterating 
    });                 
}
```

Comment: Looks like nlapiSubmitRecord also consumes governance points

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nlapiLoadRecord` uses 5 units, `nlapiLoadSearch` uses 5, then actually it is `resultSet.forEachResult` that uses another 10. On top of that, you are running `nlapiSubmitRecord` for each search result, which will use 10 more units *for each result*.

It looks to me like all you are doing with your search results is adding line items to the Category record. You do not need to submit the record until you are completely done adding all the lines. Right now, you are submitting the record after every line you add.

Move the `nlapiSubmitRecord` *after* your `forEachResult` call. This will reduce your governance (and *especially* your execution time) from 10 units per search result to just 10 units.

Answer (score 1):

Different APIs have different costs associated with them[see suiteanswers ID 10365]. Also, different types of scripts (user, scheduled, etc) have different max limits on what the total usage limit can be. [see suiteanswers ID 10481]

Your script should consume less than that limit else NetSuite will throw an error.
You can use the following line of code to measure your remaining usage at different points in your code.
nlapiLogExecution('AUDIT', 'Script Usage', 'RemainingUsage:'+nlapiGetContext().getRemainingUsage());

One strategy to avoid the max usage exceeded exception is to change the type of script to "scheduled script" since that has the maximum limit. Given that your loop is working off a search, the resultset could be huge and that may cause even a scheduled script to exceed its limits. In such case, you would want to introduce checkpoints in your code and make it reentrant. That way if you see the nlapiGetContext().getRemainingUsage() is less than your threshold, you offload the remaining work to a subsequent scheduled script.

Comment: Thank you! This is certainly helpful. I was guessing that there was a way to handle higher governance scripts.